# How to write hybrid property in Flask-SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to add the avg timestamp on my model. I have the query for the expression:

> select to_timestamp(AVG(EXTRACT(epoch from played_at))) from song;

I do not know how to do `hybrid_property` part for such a query; is it possible to use the expression directly?

This is what I currently have:

```
class Song(db.Model):
    ...
    played_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=db.func.now(), nullable=False)
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def avg_played(self):
        # what to do here?
        pass

    @avg_played.expression
    def avg_played(self):
        return db.func.to_timestamp(db.func.avg(db.func.extract(db.text('epoch'), self.played_at)))
```

But the expression gives the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "song.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I don't understandwhy that query requires a `group_by`.